# Paroh Doesn't Listen in Different Words

Tags: words, plagues-makkos, bo, va-eira

(All Pesukim cited are in Shemos.)

- 7:4: "Paroh will not listen to you."
- 7:13 (after the staffs turning into snakes): "He did not listen to them."
- 7:22 (Dam): "He did not listen to them."
- 8:11 (Tzefardeia): "He did not listen to them."
- 8:15 (Kinnim): "He did not listen to them."
- 8:28 (Arov): "He did not send the people."
- 9:7 (Dever): "He did not send the people."
- 9:12 (Shechin): "He did not listen to them."
- 9:35 (Barad): "He did not send forth Bnei Yisrael."
- 10:20 (Arbeh): "He did not send forth Bnei Yisrael."
- 10:27 (Choshech): "He did not want to send them."
- 11:10 (Bechoros, Krias Yam Suf - see Rashi): "He did not send Bnei Yisrael from his land."

---

Why does the passuk use different terminology - "listen," "send the people," "send Bnei Yisrael," "want to send," or say nothing?